# Balanced weight distribution into buckets, but with a twist (aka sharding a list into k even shards)

Tags: algorithms

Is there an existing algorithm that can solve the following problem?

**Problem**

Given an list N comprised of integers of various values, shard the list into k buckets such that:

1. The sum of the integers in each bucket are roughly evenly divided (as much as possible
2. Only consecutive integers are placed in the same bucket

**Example:**

Given k (the number of buckets) = `4`

List N = `[4 1 2 6 19 1 10 3 2 2]`

**A Valid Solution**

```
[4 1 2] [6] [19] [1 10 3 2 2]
```

(Since the bucket weights add up to `7, 6, 19, 18`)

**An Invalid Solution**

```
[1 1 2 2 2 3] [1 4 6] [10] [19]
```

(Where the bucket weights would add up to `11, 11, 10, 19`)

It's invalid because the buckets no longer contain only numbers that were adjacent in the original list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be solved as a straightforward application of dynamic programming, once you define an objective function to measure how "evenly divided" the buckets are.  Let $A[j]$ denote the value of the objective function for the best way to split integers 1..j.  Then you can compute the value of $A[j]$ given the values of $A[1],\dots,A[j-1]$ (you just consider all possibilities for how many integers go in the last bucket), so there is a dynamic programming algorithm with running time at most $O(n^2)$.

This problem is sometimes called the Linear Partition Problem, and a solution can be found in Section 8.5 of Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual".

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that this problem is called the Linear Partition Problem, with an exact solution provided in Skiena's "Algorithm Design Manual" (in section 8.5)